# Galois extension of a CM field is Galois over the maximal real subfield

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K \subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be a CM extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (not necessarily finite) and let $K^{+}$ be the maximal real subfield contained in $K$. Is it true that if $L \subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a Galois extension of $K$ (again, not necessarily finite), then $L/K^{+}$ is also a Galois extension?

It seems that if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $L$ which fixes $K^{+}$, then either $\sigma$ fixes $K$, or $\jmath \sigma$ fixes $K$, where $\jmath$ denotes the complex conjugation. However, I do not know if this is true and how to make it more precise.

Comment: What about $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})/ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$? $L$ is not Galois over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a good example, thank you :). Is it known to hold for some types of $L$?